# How do we find the uTorrent Web or BitTorrent Web torrent files from the directory (on the Mac)?

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent

uTorrent and BitTorrent the app have both released a uTorrent Web and BitTorrent Web version. It seems weird, but it seem like it is using an app, and the webpage as the "frontend" to talk to the app, perhaps kind of like a local client and server method.

This particular case it is running on a Mac.

But if the download has stuck or not going smooth, and we would like to try the torrent file using other apps, such as qBitTorrent, how do we find the `.torrent` file?  The original download might have been kicked started by clicking on a link, probably by a magnetic link and the location of the webpage was already forgotten. (like if it is five days ago and hard to find).

Using Bash:

```
sudo find / -name '*.torrent' 2>/dev/null
```

couldn't find it either.

Answer (score 1):

Magnet link is an URI link, not a file.
WebTorrent provides option to `Save .torrent File` or `Start Torrent`.
 If you want to keep the torrent file and/or use standalone client, you need to download the torrent separately.

Comment: you mean WebTorrent has that option to save the file, while uTorrent Web and BitTorrent Web may not have that option?

Comment: @deeper-understanding Each extension can be different, but every browser allows you to to download the file.

Answer (score 0):

uTorrent Web stores download information in an SQLite database.
The location is:
`C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Roaming\uTorrent Web\resume.dat`

This can be opened using most database software (DBeaver is a free one)
Then open the TORRENTS table and copy the infohash value

You can convert the infohash to a magnet link using a website such as https://hardrisk.github.io/magnet/ (Torrent name is optional)

qBittorrent and uTorrent can both just use an infohash though.

If you are planning to move your downloads to a new client you just have to add the torrent and point it at the old location (Testing 100% working using qBittorrent Q3 2023)